# Variables in Cucumber/Capybara Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am describing the behavior of a random drawing. To do this, I want to write a scenario like this:

```
Scenario: Request a drawing
  Given a drawing list has been created
  And there is a drawing code for today
  And no emails have been sent
  Then "abc@domain.com" should have no emails
  And "def@domain.com" should have no emails
  When I go to the drawing page
  Then I should see "Special Drawing"
  And the title should be "Special Drawing"
  And I fill in the following:
    |Promotion code           |#{@drawings.code}|
```

The last line is the one I'm hazy on. I have a step that creates an ivar that would make `@drawings.code` a valid expression, but I've just randomly put the interpolation syntax in there to illustrate what I'd *like* to do.

The point is, I don't know the code, and it isn't determined until the second Given is executed. What's the best way to retrieve it?

Thanks

- rails (3.0.3)
- cucumber (0.10.0)
- cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
- capybara (0.4.0)

Comment: Are you trying to treat the table as first-col = name, second-col = value? Or will there be other values below that single row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got the code generation in a given step, could you not be explicit and state the code you want to be generated that day? Presumably you've got the code generation tested else where, and you aren't testing it in that scenario.  That way, you can put the code you state in the table on the last step.

Comment: I guess it comes down to semantics and you're right it is a given, so I can specify what I want the random code to be. I just figured I'd let the code work for me through the whole pipeline as intended. And yes, the functionality of this code generation is covered well in other tests. But wouldn't it be cool if you could do something like what I wrote above? Thanks for the answer.